# How to serialise Object to JSON in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serialization, json-serialization

I am trying to serialise a huge Class with nested classes, AudioClip and texture2D. I implemented ISerializable interface and marked all classes with SerializableAttribute. I use JsonUtility to convert to Json and back.

Everything works well except Textures2D, Textures2D[] and AudioClip. The implementation of ISerializable method is below:

```
[Serializable]
public class Illustration : ISerializable
{
    public Texture2D Image = new Texture2D(256, 256);

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue(nameof(Image), Image.EncodeToPNG(), typeof(byte[]));
    }

    private Illustration(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        Image.LoadImage(info.GetValue(nameof(Image), typeof(byte[])) as byte[]);
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class CustomAnimation : ISerializable
{
    public Texture2D[] Images;

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue(nameof(Images), Images.Select(x => x.EncodeToPNG()).ToArray(), typeof(byte[][]));
    }

    private CustomAnimation(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        var textures = info.GetValue(nameof(Images), typeof(byte[][])) as byte[][];
        if (textures != null)
        {
            var imagesAndTextures = Images.Zip(textures, (i, t) => new {Images = i, textures = t});
            foreach (var it in imagesAndTextures)
            {
                it.Images.LoadImage(it.textures);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expect this code to make a JSON with byte arrays of Textures, but I get this:

```
"Illustrations": [
                {
                    "Image": {
                        "instanceID": 34540
                    }
                }
]
```

Why do I have this instanceID? I need the binary texture to save it in text file then. It is not a runtime object.

Comment: I gave an example in this answer
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54159017/is-it-possible-to-serialize-sprites-in-unity/54164247#54164247)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing the texture as byte array in json is not a good idea, no one does it and there must be a reason for it.

If you really needed to, then you'd need the byte array from your texture, most likely as jpeg so it is smaller:

```
byte [] tex = texture.EncodeToJpg();
var str = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(tex);
JsonObject json = new JsonObject();   // pseudo code for a json parser
json.Add("Illustration", str);
```

and the other way around:

```
string str = json.GetString("Illustration");
byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str);
```

But the way it is actually done, the json contains the url of the image only.

There is little purpose to store the texture as stringified byte array since a jpg is already a txt file containing a byte array most likely as binary. So, with the second approach you would be splitting your json and make it actually readable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot Serialize the image itself. It has been load to the memory and the image is a reference.

Another thing is that if you change any property of a texture, it will gerenate a new one, loosing the reference of the original one too.

What you can do is to create another array with the texture name and then apply when you load your JSon.

Answer (score 0):

your approach looks all right - I think it fails because of inner workings of UnityEngine, where parts of the data are on the managed/c# side and parts on the native/c++ side. It gets even more complicated for textures, which can live either on the GPU or both in Ram/GPU if they are marked as readable. The wierdest case is rendertextures, which live perfectly on the edge, and have some wierd behaviours (i.e. they don't get garbage collected even when you loose the reference).

The workaround seems pretty trivial - make a serializable byte[] field, fill it with encoded texture (or the zip as you do) - maybe even in advance (before you serialize).